# Why does Apple issue new common stock every year (even though it has enough cash)?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-valuation, balance-sheet

Apple has so much cash. It really doesn’t have to raise additional capital yet every single year it issues new common stock. Why is that?

Comment: Where are you seeing Apple issuing stock? They've been issuing _debt_ and using it to _buy back_ stock.

Comment: @DStanley why debt when they have so much cash?  Is it because they'd have to first repatriate the cash and pay taxes on it?

Comment: @RonJohn Partly, and partly because they can borrow money for next to nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Apple offers share options as an incentive for its employees.  When the employees exercise the options, the shares have to come from somewhere.

Comment: The question is whether Apple issues **new** shares to do that, or whether they **buy back** existing shares in order to pass out to employees.

Comment: The shares may always have existed, not released for sale but held to distribute to employees over time.

Comment: @RonJohn, I believe the stock issued to employees and the stock purchased in the buyback program are uncorrelated, although they do, of course, offset each other.